# How do I order a list which is a property within a C# object?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have an object like below which has a few properties and one of them is a list. How can I order that list by one of the properties within that list?

Example:

```
Student std = new Student() { StudentID = 1, 
                                      StudentName = "Bill", 
                                      Age = 20, 
                                      Address = "New York",
                                      List<Object> Subject = new(){item1,item2, item3};
                                      
                                    };
```

Each of the items will contain different properties of data types and assuming it contains an `int` datatype of score, I want to order the `list` Subject by ascending order of score.

I tried using `LINQ` like this: `result.Student[i].Subject.Sort((x, y) => x.score.CompareTo(y.score));` but didnt help

I also tried something like this: `result.Student[i].Subject.Sort();`

Comment: Use `.OrderBy` method.

Comment: Your list is a `List<string>`, how can you order it by a "score"? Your question lacks a lot of information. Why is it a `List<string>` at all and not a `List<ExamResult>` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If Subjects is a List then you should do something List

Subjects.ToList().OrderBy( s=> s.Name):

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way that the array is nested inside of the `Subjects` array is very weird, especially since the list currently used is a `list<string>`, which cannot contain integers.

Consider making a new `Subject` class or structure to store the subject name, score, and letter grade.

If you want to sort a list of objects by one of the object's properties, use Linq, like so: `Subjects.OrderBy(subject => subject.score);`

(assuming that the `Subjects` array is full of `Subject` classes or structs with a property called "score")